# How to execute only a specific function from another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have two files:

`test2.py`:

```
def fun():
    print "from fun"
print  "from test2"
```

`test.py`:

```
from test2 import fun
print "in text"
fun()
```

I want to execute *only* the `fun` function from `test2.py`, but I also got `from test2`.

How can I use only the function I want?

Comment: Why do you have a `print` statement at the top level of `test2.py`? You could guard it behind `if __name__ == '__main__`, but why do you need it at all?

Answer (score 3):

In `test2.py` you need to make sure "from test2" is only printed when the program is being run by itself.

You can do it like this:

**test2.py**

```
def fun():
    print "from fun"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print  "from test2"
```